# Impala: Get the list of matching partitions

Tags: cloudera, impala

We have an impala table that is partitioned by as `year=yyyy/month=mm/day=dd/hour=hh`. One of the client applications can send `select` queries to it with a `from` and a `to` date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

Now, for eg. if the `from` date is set to say `01/11/2019` and `to` date is set to `29/02/2020`, in order to use the partitions, the imapla SQL should be something like:

```
select * from table where (year = 2019 AND month in (11, 12)) OR (year = 2020 AND month in (1,2))
```

Is there a way in impala SQL to convert the dates to the right partitions above?

Unfortunately the client in question is a BI tool that does not allow programming the logic above.

Comment: Being a BI tool is no excuse for not using partition columns in a query.

Comment: can  you try - WHERE table_year BETWEEN year(from_dt) AND year(to_dt) AND table_month BETWEEN month(from_dt) AND month(to_dt). But i dont think this will follow partition.

Comment: @koushiksinharoy This would unfortunately work for the example above where the timeframe overlaps 2 years.

Comment: can you pls try this bad sql then -  WHERE 
CAST( concat (CAST(table_year AS string), CAST(table_month AS string)) AS BIGINT) 
BETWEEN 
CAST( concat (CAST(YEAR(from_dt) AS string), CAST(MONTH(from_dt) AS string)) AS BIGINT)
AND
CAST( concat (CAST(YEAR(to_dt) AS string), CAST(MONTH(to_dt) AS string)) AS BIGINT)

Comment: @koushiksinharoy You call it bad, I call it smart :) That indeed works. I had to `lpad` the month before the concat, but the idea works and follows the right partitions. Could you make this the answer and I will accept it. Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you too :) posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Solution is -
`WHERE 
CAST( concat (CAST(table_year AS string), CAST(table_month AS string)) AS BIGINT) 
BETWEEN 
CAST( concat (CAST(YEAR(from_dt) AS string), CAST(MONTH(from_dt) AS string)) AS BIGINT) AND 
CAST( concat (CAST(YEAR(to_dt) AS string), CAST(MONTH(to_dt) AS string)) AS BIGINT)`

Basically, concatenate year and month to make a string and then convert it to an integer to use between function. This will work form any date to any date range. Since you have partition on month and year, this filter will follow partition and work just fine.